# In C# Web API, when I POST multiple data in the Postman it returns 'null' value

Tags: c#, post, webapi

`

```
[HttpGet]
        public List<studTB> StudentsList()
        {
            StudentEntities studentEntities = new StudentEntities();

            return studentEntities.studTBs.ToList();
        } 

// POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public IEnumerable<studTB> Post([FromBody] studTB stud)
        {
            List<studTB> studentEntities = new List<studTB>();
            studentEntities.Add(stud);

            return studentEntities;
        }
```

`[image][image]

1. How to POST multiple JSON data.
2. I want to Post data by using JSON format.

Comment: Yes, I will add a screenshot.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2):

In Postman, your body is an array of `studTB` objects, but in C#, your method parameter is a single `studTB` object. Those need to match.

Either only post one at a time (as a JSON object, no array), or change the C# to accept a list.

```
public IEnumerable<studTB> Post([FromBody] List<studTB> studs)
{
    List<studTB> studentEntities = new List<studTB>();
    studentEntities.AddRange(studs); // change to Range to add multiple

    return studentEntities;
}
```